# Two way binding issue with directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am adding data to `filteredData` from `data` variable. After some time I add data to `filteredData` from `data` using directive. Data should be updated after specified amount of time but it isn't. Any idea whats wrong here? **Check out plunkr here : [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/3y8FUOEYiLI1MviIWQrV?p=preview)**

View looks like:

```
 <ul my-dir data="data" filtered-data="filteredData">
     <li ng-repeat="d in filteredData">
         {{d.name}}
     </li>
 </ul>
```

Controller variables:

```
$scope.data = [{name:"Yanni"},{name:"Wally"},{name:"Mohd"},{name:"Darek"}];

$scope.filteredData = $scope.data.slice(0,2);
```

`my-dir` directive:

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('myDir', [function () {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      data: "=",
      filteredData: "="
    },
    link: function (scope, iElement, iAttrs) {

        setTimeout( function () {
          console.log("in");
          console.log(scope.data);
          var nextData = scope.data.slice(2,4);
          console.log(nextData);
          scope.$evalAsync(
                    function( ) {
                      scope.filteredData.push(nextData);
                    });
        },3000);
    }
};
}]);
```

Comment: use angular service '$timeout' and not the javascript setTimeout function. 'setTimeout' will not be executed in the angular lifecycle and won't recognise data updates. As alternative you could also wrap your update function in a `scope.$apply()`

Comment: @Michael doesnt matter.

Comment: What doesn't matter??? Of course it does!

Comment: @Michael : instead of timeout there can be any event like scroll or click or someting.

Comment: `nextData` is an array of the size 2. then you add this array to the `filteredData`. you end up with an array in another array. you have to push each single item to the filteredData array [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/kOFTzGqt41BcUBMKLCK7?p=preview), or us the array.contcat() function, but I don't know if this works with objects [array concat](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_concat_array.asp)

Answer (score 0):

```
setTimeout( function () {
  console.log("in");
  console.log(scope.data);
  var nextData = scope.data.slice(2,4);
  console.log(nextData);
  scope.$evalAsync( function( ) {
      for (var i = 0; i < nextData.length; i++) {
        scope.filteredData.push(nextData[i]);
      }
  });
}, 3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

to close this question @Michael s answer:

> use angular service `$timeout` and not the javascript setTimeout function. `setTimeout` will not be executed in the angular lifecycle and won't recognise data updates. As alternative you could also wrap your update function in a `scope.$apply()`